# uninitialized proxy passed to persist()

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am getting "uninitialized proxy passed to persist()" during persist of an object.  What does this mean?

`org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()`

The entity has one many to many relationship, as

`@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="brand_id") private Brand brand;`

and one OneToOne relationship as,

```
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL , fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="addressToSendAC_FK")
    private BrandAddress addressToSendAC;
```

Are these causing the error ?

Edit:

stacktrace added.

```
[#|2011-06-30T14:36:29.920+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=58;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1153)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:678)
    at com.wompower.entity.accessor.brand.BrandRegistry$11.execute(BrandRegistry.java:271)
    at com.wompower.entity.accessor.common.AbstractEntityAccessor.doInTransaction(AbstractEntityAccessor.java:82)
    at com.wompower.entity.accessor.brand.BrandRegistry.addBrandAC(BrandRegistry.java:267)
    at com.wompower.backing.brand.ActivationCodeBacking.generateActivationCode(ActivationCodeBacking.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:98)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:772)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1267)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:820)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:314)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:729)

Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:799)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:791)
    at org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:450)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:799)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:791)
    at org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:450)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.|#]

[#|2011-06-30T14:36:29.920+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=58;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:808)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:782)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:786)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:672)
    ... 63 more
```

Comment: I think this is transaction issue.Can you please post entire code?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide much details it's hard to tell what happened for sure, but I will guess that you got proxy but never hit the database to get object information before trying to persist object. Relevant piece from Hibernate documentation:

```
If the class is mapped with a proxy, load() just returns an uninitialized proxy 
and does not actually hit the database until you invoke a method of the proxy.
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-loading

Comment: really sorry for my late reply.. missed the email alert.. still not working.. added the stacktrace in the original post if it helps... If there are any specific details I need to provide, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**
Make sure you correctly initiate **Hibernate session** / use **@Transactional** annotation.

**Background:**
Stack: JPA/Hibernate, Spring Boot 2.7.6

With an introduction of a method in my service that had to persist aggregate entity with other referenced entities I got the same exception:

`uninitialized proxy passed to persist()`

Following TTD, this exact invocation worked without any issue in integration test. Finally found out that test method was automatically wrapped in a transaction, where the @Transaction annotation was missing in my service method as before there were no DB actions present.

After adding springframework @Transactional annotation on the service method persistence works as expected.